# How to make bootstrap columns automatically resize when element overflows them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a BootStrap 5 row, the columns of which will always remain the same, even if the content inside of them overflows the column. How do I make it so that when content is larger than the column, the column expands in size?

[image: Cards overflowing columns]

As you can see, the columns (purple) let the cards inside of them overflow, therefore causing them to collide with other cards. What I want is for the columns to expand when the content inside of them is bound to overflow.

HTML for rows and columns:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="header">User</h1>
            <div class="card card-large border-0 me-1">
                <div class="card-body shadow">
                    <div class="row row-cols-2">
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 16px; width: 50px">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-user-pen" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-column">
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Username: </a>
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Plan: </a>
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Discord: </a>
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Date of registration: </a>
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Used searches: /</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <a class="btn shadow text-white me-1" style="background-color: #7289da">Link Discord</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary shadow text-white me-1">Change password</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger shadow text-white" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#logout">Log out</a>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="logout" data-bs-backdrop="logout" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style=" width: 25rem">
                                <div class="modal-content text-white">
                                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #0e0e0e">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="col-1" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 16px; width: 50px">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-8 mt-4">
                                                Are you sure you wish to log out?
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer border-0 justify-content-center" style="background-color: #0e0e0e">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button data-bs-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteCookie()">Log out</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="col">
            <h1 class="header">Plan</h1>
            <div class="card card-large border-0 me-1">
                <div class="card-body shadow">
                    <div class="row row-cols-2">
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 16px; width: 50px">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-tag" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-column">
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Plan: </a>
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Date of Purchase: </a>
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Date of Expiration: </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary shadow text-white me-1" @click="">Upgrade</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger shadow text-white">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="header">API</h1>
            <div class="card card-large border-0 me-3">
                <div class="card-body shadow">
                    <div class="row row-cols-2">
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 16px; width: 50px">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-code" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right-column">
                            <a class="header row pt-2">Used searches: /</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary shadow text-white me-1 disabled">API docs</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary shadow text-white me-1" onclick="">Copy API key</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary shadow text-white">Regenerate API key</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `col-lg-4` in column `row` like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    //content
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    //content
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    //content
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information, please visit this link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/#how-they-work